# Fatal error – Face tracking is not supported on this device

Tags: swift, arkit, truedepth-camera

I want to enable ARFaceTrackingConfiguration on my app but i am having problem with it. I am using iPhone 7 which has Apple A10 Fusion-64 bit chip but still getting that fatal error. Can you help me with this?

I enabled permissions on the info.plist and i am cheking .isSupported in ARFaceTrackingCOnfiguration

```
let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
sceneView.session.run(configuration)

guard ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.isSupported else {
    fatalError("Face tracking is not supported on this device")
}
```

is it because the front camera of Iphone 7 is not TrueDepth camera?

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: I am getting ( Session (0x104f02e60): did fail with error: Error Domain=com.apple.arkit.error Code=100 "Unsupported configuration." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unsupported configuration., NSLocalizedFailureReason=The provided configuration is not supported on this device.}) type of error

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code where it is failing?

Comment: let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
        
        guard ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.isSupported else {
            fatalError("Face tracking is not supported on this device")
        }

Comment: Please put the code in your question, in a code block so it is actually readable.

Comment: I am creating congig like this and simply running it but it is failing in fatalError() throwing and error

Comment: Does my answer help your case?) To clarify it for your specific case — because face tracking configuration is available only on iOS devices with a front-facing TrueDepth camera `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration` won't run on iPhone 7.

Comment: @IvanNesterenko yeah i found out that it will not work on iPHONE 7, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't run `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration` without TrueDepth camera.
Check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfacetrackingconfiguration) for more info

> Face tracking is available only on iOS devices with a front-facing TrueDepth camera

You can also check if the device can run this configuration by calling `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.isSupported`